# Can I draw lines into a QTableView/Widget?

Tags: qt, qtableview

If the user selects a cell in a `QTableView`, I like to indicate where other cells are with the same value. For this I like to draw lines from the selected cell to the others.

If this would be a `QGraphicsView` it would be easy, but how can I draw into a `QTableView`?

Comment: Your best bet might be to use an [item delegate](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#setItemDelegate).

Comment: override paintEvent, then call all the lines (probably best to cache this into a QPixmap...). To generate the lines, take the current index from the selection model, take the Qt::DisplayRole string from the model, and iterate over all items currently in viewport (indexAt at (0,0) and (width,height)). If they match.. you can draw a line to them using visualRect. Alternatively you can select them all, then you don't need to override paintEvent. Personally, I would just change their font to be bold.. then you don't even need to search.. just do this in the item delegate.

Comment: If you would want to indicate with something else, it would be much easier. For example, but changing background colors of those cells, or making their fonts bold. But if you want to draw lines... you have to paint them yourself.